# Proving two summations equivalent

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, summation

Let $h_n$ be an infinite sequence. I need to show that:

\begin{align}\dfrac{1}{1+x}H\left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{i=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}{k\choose i}x^kh_i
\end{align}

where $H(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty h_kx^k$

Transforming the LHS we get: $\dfrac{1}{1+x}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty h_kx^k(1+x)^{-k}$
\begin{align}
=& \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty h_kx^k(1+x)^{-(k+1)} \\
=& \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty h_kx^k\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i{k+i\choose i}x^i
\end{align}

This last step is by [Newtons generalized binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem). Now moving the $h_k$ and $x^k$ we get:

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i{k+i\choose i}x^{i+k}h_k 
\end{equation}

Where can I go from here? I typed both of these double sums into a CAS (without $h_n$ and found that they both converge to $1$ for any value of $x$). Intuition tells me that it is a matter of interpreting the $i+k$ and the subscript on $h$ to find that the LHS = RHS

All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Just move the $h_k x^k$ into the inner sum, and you are done... nicely, BTW.

Comment: I think you are not looking correctly what the LHS and RHS are. Or could you go into more detail?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you comment on the post in the link you gave me? I commented asking what the $\delta$ means and some details about going to the triple sum and then back to the double sum.